# Error while creating objects with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having trouble when I try to create a new object in ExtJS. First I create a new object, then create another object of the same class. In that class I have a property, called 'form'. This property is of type 'object'. I'll show below:

```
Ext.define('ExampleClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    form: {
        last: null
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        if(this.form.last == null) {
            this.form.last = this;
        }
        else {
            console.log(this.form);
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The code is simple. When I create the first object, ok. When I create the second object, the console shows the first object (entering the else condition). This only happens when I have an object as a property of the class. This can be a bug of Ext or I really need to clone all objects in the class every time I create a new object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your form in `initComponent`, since you want a separate instance for each `ExampleClass` instance.

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.form = {
        last: null
    };
    ...
```

In your current implementation, there is only *one* `form` object, since `Ext.define` is called only *once*. Then on instantiantion a reference to the existing object is passed to the instances.

Comment: In other words, the way the OP created the form,  it is  stored on the prototype of `ExampleClass` and shared by all instances. I never add any objects to the prototype that aren't strings, numbers or booleans to avoid this bug.

Comment: I'm doing this right now on all my app. Removing all the properties that aren't strings, numbers or booleans. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just the way inheritance works in JavaScript. See http://jsfiddle.net/GseUG/ for a simple example. (However, it's a common pitfall that I've ran into frequently)